# Canvas - Reset pixels around

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to reset pixels to transparent like this:
[image]

Consider white as transparent. How to calculate those pixels.
If reset 50% it would be half image, if 100% it would be entire image hidden. On the picture is 35%.
Circle is just for show. It can be any square image.

Comment: Nothing. I'm looking for math algorithm to search those pixels.

Comment: @holden321 In that case, this question might be better on Math.SE. I posted an algorithm request there and got a very helpful response, then went and did the programming part myself.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I'll try your algorithm first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each point on the canvas, calculate the angle to your central point. In basic terms:

```
angle = Math.atan2(y - cy, x - cx);
```

Where `(cx,cy)` are the coordinates of your central point, and `(x,y)` the coordinates of the current pixel being examined.

If this angle is within the range you want to nuke, clear that pixel.

To make this simpler, add `Math.PI*3/2`, then do `% Math.PI*2`, and finally multiply by `100/(Math.PI*2)` to get a number in the range 0 (up) counter-clockwise to 100.

Now it's a simple case of seeing if that number is less than your target percentage, and if so clear it.

Comment: Work almost fine. Only 100% or 0% at the top and the bottom. Should be 0% at top, and 50% at bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/holden321/E89FQ/

Comment: `%` and `*` have same precedence, so that's where it was getting mixed up. Also, the `y` axis is pointing down in canvas (forgot that, oops!), so it should be `cy - y`. [Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E89FQ/2/)

Comment: Yeah! It works now. Thank you very much. I can pay you for your job if you want.

Comment: Hehe, glad I could help. If you want to support me, you can always check out my game and buy stuff there, that way you get more stuff too while still supporting my work ^_^